# What is the mongo compound index keyword arrangement rule? Numbers first, strings later?

Tags: mongodb, sharding, unique-index, compound-index

When I used numbers as keys, the compound index prefixes created were not as expected。

To define a compound index:

```
admin> use TestDB
TestDB> db.createCollection('coll')
TestDB> db.coll.createIndex({4:1,1:-1},{unique:true})
TestDB> db.coll.getIndexex()
```

Output

```
[
  { v: 2, key: { _id: 1 }, name: '_id_' },
  { v: 2, key: { '1': -1, '4': 1 }, name: '1_-1_4_1', unique: true }
]
```

**I expected 4 to be the prefix of the index, but it turned out to be 1, why?**
It looks like the sorting happens

And when I use strings as keywords, the results are completely inconsistent。

Following：

```
TestDB> db.createCollection("coll2")
TestDB> db.coll2.createIndex({'s':1, 'a':-1},{unique:true})
```

Output

```
[
  { v: 2, key: { _id: 1 }, name: '_id_' },
  { v: 2, key: { s: 1, a: -1 }, name: 's_1_a_-1', unique: true }
]
```

What? It doesn't seem to be sorting.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this issue](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/MONGOSH-1037), which references the official specification, this is a result of how Javascript works.

For example, in Node:

```
$ node
Welcome to Node.js v16.17.0.
Type ".help" for more information.
> var pattern = { 4: 1, 1: -1 }
undefined
> pattern
{ '1': -1, '4': 1 }
```

You can see similar behavior in [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aengjLh5/).

If you are attempting to create indexes that have numeric keys, you will need to do so with a different language/driver.